# Is there any difference between "do well in a job interview", "do well at a job interview" and "do well on a job interview"?

Tags: prepositions, difference

Could you tell me if there is any difference between *do well in a job interview*, *do well at a job interview* and *do well on a job interview*? For example:

> If Kate does well **in** the job interview, that'll definetly call for a celebration.
>
> If Kate does well **at** the job interview, that'll definetly call for a celebration.
>
> If Kate does well **on** the job interview, that'll definetly call for a celebration.

Comment: Perhaps on and in can be used for when the job interview is going on, and at at the place where you are interviewed for the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although all these prepositions have very different meanings and usage, there are quite a number of occasions where they can all be used interchangeably without much change in meaning, because a situation can often be described from different perspectives that merit using a different preposition.

For example, an actor might appear *in* a play, *on* the stage, *at* a theatre (*John is appearing on stage in Hamlet at The Grand Theatre*).

The word "interview" is used interchangeably to refer to the *process* of being interviewed and the *event* that takes place. So, a person goes *into* an interview; while they are there they are *at* the interview; and, as an interview is something you attend, it is acceptable to say you went *on* an interview just as you would say you went *on* vacation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But what about "do well in a job interview", "do well at a job interview", "do well on a job interview"? Do they mean exactly the same?

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope you've just written the same sentence three times, so yes, they mean exactly the same.

Comment: I'm sorry) I have corrected it

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope As my answer explains, it depends whether "interview" is being used to mean the event, or the process. "Do well *in* a job interview" would mean you performed well in the interview *process*; "do well *at* a job interview" would mean you peformed well *while you were at the interview event*. In reality, most people would just use them interchangeably without too much thought about this, because they do all ultimately refer to the same event, just like my theatre example.